# Not able to pass the $_SESSION['usr'] value after php login page

Tags: php, html, session

Index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usr'])){
header("Location: browse.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

                        <form class="form col-md-12 center-block" action="login.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" name="mail" required="true">
                                    </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" name="pass" required="true">
                                    </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" name="Signin" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
</div>
                      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Login.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['Signin'])) {
$con=mysqli_connect(********);
    if (!$con)
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
        $mail=isset($_POST['mail']) ? $_POST['mail']:null;
        $pass=isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass']:null;

        $sql2 = "SELECT mail, password FROM user_data where mail='$mail' and password='$pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
$_SESSION['usr']=$mail; 
mysql_close($con); // Closing Connection
header("Location: browse.php");
}
else {
header("Location: index.php");
}
}
?>
```

Browse.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION[‘usr’])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<html>
<!-- content here -->
<html>
```

In the above code, the mail value from index.php is given to $_SESSION['usr'] in login.php which then redirects to browse.php. Here, the !isset($_SESSION[‘usr’]) is true, also $_SESSION[‘usr’] carries nothing in it and hence loads back to index.php. Can i get a solution for the above code?

Comment: You have funky quotes. The syntax highlighting makes it obvious. Change them to normal single quotes. `if(isset($_SESSION[‘usr’])){` should be `if(isset($_SESSION['usr'])){`

Comment: plus store a hash; not plain text

Comment: Thanks John, yes i have corrected the quotes,however, it does not work.

Comment: you need to update your question then with the codes you are now using for all the curly quotes.

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a $_SESSION a value like these

```
$_SESSION['user'] = 'yes';
```

then on your browse.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['usr'])){
  echo"<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also @BrylleDelrosario, what can i do to get user details in browse.php once logged in? i tried below : 

`$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
$_SESSION['usr']='yes'; // Initializing Session
$_SESSION['username'] = $user['mail'];
echo $_SESSION['username'];
}`

However, $_SESSION['username'] has nothing in it.. also when i try placing it in browse.php, it does not give me the user details.

Comment: Glad i helped you out :)